# does the word "Loading" that switches to the word "Advertisement" violate adsense policies?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-adsense-policies

In countless tests on webpagetest.org, when I test my site, the first thing that appears on the screen very early is the word "Advertisement". It's the header I use right above a google adsense advertisement to indicate it as such.

What I was thinking is having it where the word is "Loading" right above the advertisement block, then when the styles are applied (after the ad begins to load), the word "Loading" finally changes to "Advertisement".

I see this as a user experience enhancement but the question is, would the google adsense team complain to me if I execute this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourced directly from the Google support site (https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Placing_ads_under_a_misleading_heading)

> It's important that visitors to your site are not misled in any way and are able to easily distinguish content from Google ads. This policy prohibits placing ads under misleading headings such as "resources" or "helpful links". Publishers may only label ads with either "Advertisements" or "Sponsored Links". No other variations are permitted.

By this advice provided directly by Google having the label say loading... is not an issue as long as the ad is not being displayed at the time, once the ad is displayed then it should change to Advertisement which is what you are saying you are doing so you are fine with the terms and the rules as Google provides. Just be aware Google has a tendency to change the rules whenever it suites them so do keep apprised of any changes to the terms as just because it is allowed at the moment doesn't mean it will be allowed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

That is not mislabeling, that is not dragging unnatural attention. That is just what it says and what it says is what it actually is - it is loading.

I don't see any problem with that.